# gtol parameter issues [mystic]

Tags: python, optimization, mystic

I am trying to optimize a function using the *mystic* library in Python, and have a general question about the *gtol* parameter.

The parameter space I'm searching in, is of high dimension (30-40), and for this reason, it seemed fitting for me to set *gtol* = 40000. Strangely, the algorithm seems to stop after 30000 iterations, although I specified the *gtol* as 40000, which (by my knowledge) means that the algorithm should have 40000 identical iterations before it stops running.

My function call is pretty basic:

```
stepmon = VerboseLoggingMonitor(1, 1)
result  = diffev2(utilss, x0=[1/value]*value, bounds=[(0,0.2)] * value,  npop=150, gtol=40000, disp=True, full_output=True, itermon=stepmon
```

I checked the merit function's evolution, and it is flat around the 29000th iteration. The last 1000 iterations are identical, but it already stops there instead of running the rest of the 39000 required *gtol* iterations.

Am I misinterpreting the *gtol* parameter? Or what am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the `mystic` author.  That is the correct interpretation for `gtol`, however, you are probably ignoring `maxiter` (and `maxfun`) which is the maximum number of iterations (and function evaluations) to perform.

If you don't set `maxiter` (default is `None`), then the I believe that the default setting for `diffev2` is `10 * nDim * nPop`.  Try setting `maxiter=100000`, or something like that.

If the termination message says `Warning: Maximum number of iterations has been exceeded`, then `maxiter` caused it to stop.

Comment: Thank you, Mike McKerns. 

I'm not sure if your formula for the default setting is right, since nDim * nPop should be 4500 in my case. But still, it explains the outcome, and I do get the termination message.

Comment: Update: checked the source code and its defined as:

N * self.nPop * iterscale

with iterscale = 10, as you said. It's strange then that I'm getting 30000 iterations here.

Comment: well `N` is usually `nDim`, but it's actually `len(self.population[0])`. Regardless, `maxiter` is what you need to set.

Comment: Thanks. I just found the actual issue was the default EvaluationsLimit, which was set to 4500000 in my case, which corresponded to 30000 iterations each time (because of the population size).